# ActiveRecord scope "default" result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So let's say I want to check for nils in an ActiveRecord scope:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :closest, ->(point) {
    return nil unless point # How can I return the ActiveSupport::Relation here?
    # other code goes below
  }
end
```

Comment: which field should be nil?

Comment: If point is nil for example, I want to return Person.all. But doing Person.all does not allow for flexibility because I might want to do: Person.closest(1).where(name: "something")
I also don't want .all because I don't want the relation to evaluate

Comment: `all` doesn't reset the scope. If called on the class, it returns the default scope. If called on a relation, it returns the same relation.

Comment: @ahmacleod I think you are right; all is what I am looking for. It seems that it's not evaluating in Rails 4 and `Person.all.to_sql` is valid

Comment: @Abdo, please edit the question and add details you put in comment .. so that people with same problem can get solution quicker.

Comment: @illusionist I have updated my answer below. I'll be able to accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit/Solution**

As mentioned in the comments above, and as @ahmacleod pointed out, `all` is what we're looking for

```
scope :closest, ->(point) {
  point.nil? ? all : where(point: point)
}
```

**End edit**

<strike>I think I have found what I am looking for and it's `unscoped`</strike>

```
scope :closest, ->(point) {
  point.nil? ? unscoped : where(point: point)
}
```

The problem is that if I chain this, I would lose prior scopes if I use this after them.

Answer (score 2):

You can just return self for it to return the default scope:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.closest(point = nil)
    point.nil? ? self : where(point: point)
  end

end
```

Comment: Whereas this is useful, when I do: `Person.where(name: 'Abdo').closest` , the result is of type `Person`. I can't do `.to_sql` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `point` parameter as optional. Something like this:

```
scope :closest, -> (point = '') {
  where(point: point)     
}
```

This way, the scope will return a ActiveRecord::Relation every time.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks =) I am looking for a way to return a "default ActiveRecord::Relation" ... Any clue?